# Multithreaded debugger for Eclipse

Tags: multithreading, eclipse, debugging

Is there any multithreaded debugging option in Eclipse so that I can see the breakpoints of all threads when the event occurs.

If not is there any multithreaded debugging tool?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, the debugging in Eclipse supports debugging multithreaded-applications (if that's what you meant), just take a look at the Debug-perspective: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/images/debug-breadcrumb-3.png   Or maybe I just misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 8):

Click on your breakpoint in the Breakpoints view, select "suspend VM" from the menu. When that's hit the whole VM will suspend, not just the thread.

Answer (score 0):

**About downvotes**: 
Before you downvote that answer, let me clarify that I was replying to a question related to Eclipse + EPIC and multi-threaded debugging. With the time they decided to rephrase the question and my answer, that was correct, got out of context! So watch out from the policies of this site!

**UDPATE**: Finally solved :)

I'll get back to you as soon as I get something else in this topic.

Sorry to say, currently EPIC doesn't suport multithreaded programs. It's stated in their user guide, unless there's anything new that's the official statment.

> EPIC does not currently include support for debugging multi-threaded programs.

[Here you have the reference](http://www.epic-ide.org/guide/ch06s04.php)

The alternative, [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/) I have no experience, but you may want to give a try.

**UPDATE:**

I know is an older post, but is worth for any future problems. I found the way to debug perl programs with threads.

In my case,

- Eclipse 3.7
- EPIC Plugin 0.6.42
- ActivePerl 5.14.2 Build 1402 (64bits)

We are not yet there, the ActivePerl requires a trick.
Following the instructions of [this bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=56225).
One of the comments mention to replace in Cwd.pm module the single commas with curly brackets ... more precisely

In C:\Perl64\lib\Cwd.pm

the line 758 has the following code

```
if (eval 'defined &DynaLoader::boot_DynaLoader') {
```

just replace it with the following

```
if (eval { defined &DynaLoader::boot_DynaLoader; }) {
```

In my case I can debug multithreaded perl scripts and break inside the thread even with detach.

Hope it helps, happy debugging.

Comment: Apparently not after the edit in 2012, I'm sure that before was talking about EPIC...

Comment: I don't know what @ruffp did on that, but also your response was edited after that. Anyway you should remove it from here and create other thread for it if you want.

Comment: Well I find it wrong that after 2 years of that questions, they changed the content of it and suddenly my answer loses value and I get down on points! Just not too serious!